# Why do I need to specify an absolute path for res.sendFile() instead of relative one?

Tags: javascript, express, http, path, web-development-server

Assuming my index.js is in same directory with my index.html. There is also a folder css containing styles.css.

```
/
  |- index.js
  |- index.html
  |- css/styles.css
```

In the index.html, I can specify my css style with relative path and it would direct to css/styles.css which is relative to my index.html

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

However, in the index.js when my express server receives a GET request instead of

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile("index.html"); // type Error
});
```

I have to specify an absolute path

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

Considering the behavior of index.html when it can locate correctly (show no error) the relative path  `css/styles.css`. Why the same logic couldn't be applied to index.js ?

Why the file system doesn't behave the same as when I specify a relative path in index.html ?

note: I understand that the other way is to specifying a root. However, the main point of the question is why I have to use the absolute path instead of relative one (why the error?)

Comment: You don't need to send index.html manually. Express will do it for you, should you simply specify the folder where it resides with `app.use( express.static( assetsFolderPath ) )`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative path. The path is just resolved from the current working directory which is:

- Likely to be the root of your Node.js project (and not the root of your static files within that project) in your development environment
- Likely to be somewhere (a) different and (b) less useful when you have a production environment (which might launch it via PM2 via systemd or be an AWS lambda function)

Computing an absolute path using `__dirname` means you are explicitly making it relative to the location of the JS module which is always going to be in the same location relative to your static files when you have them bundled together.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer but I think I don't really grasp it fully from a beginner standpoint. With the specified directory as mention above in my question, I think that my node.js project directory is also where my index.js (and other files) resides? (I'm pretty sure that everything of my site is in a folder. The structure of that root folder is described in my question. It also contains node_modules, package.json etc )